# Discord.js - .createdAt() is not a valid function

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to do is whenever someone joins the server, the bot sends a rich embed with their ID, their user creation date and the new total members, but whenever i run it and test it, it says that `.createdAt()` is not a valid function, so i'm completely lost as to what to do.

---

```
client.on("guildMemberAdd", member => {
  let mlogchannel = member.guild.channels.find((channel => channel.name === "member-logging"));
  if (mlogchannel) {
    console.log(client.users.find(user => user.id === member.id).createdAt())
    var cdate = moment.utc(User.createdAt()).format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, HH:mm");
    const sInfo = new Discord.RichEmbed()
      .setTitle(`Member joined`)
      .setAuthor(`${member.displayName}`)
      .setColor(8528115)
      .setFooter(`User ID: ${member.id}`)
      .setTimestamp()
      .setThumbnail(member.user.createdAt())
      .addField("Total members", `${Guild.members.filter(member => !member.user.bot).size}`, true)
      .addField("Creation Date:", `${cdate}`, true);
    let ageS = moment(cdate).fromNow(true)
    let ageA = ageS.split(" ");
    if (ageA[1] = "days" && ageA[2] >= 30) {
      Guild.channels.find((channel => channel.name === "member-logging").send(sInfo));
      mlogchannel.send("**WARNING!**\nThis account is less than 30 days old and may have been made to bypass a server mute or ban!")
    }
    if (ageA[1] != "days") {
      mlogchannel.send(sInfo)
    }
    if (!mlogchannel) {
      return console.log(`${Guild.name}:${Guild.ID} Has not set up a member log channel!`)
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 3):

`User.createdAt` is a *property* of User, not a method. So instead of `.setThumbnail(member.user.createdAt())`, it would be `.setThumbnail(member.user.createdAt)`.