# Discord.js days since account creation

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Is there any way to give a user a certain role when they join the server, if they have been registered to discord for less than 10 days.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54393807/discord-js-createdat-is-not-a-valid-function

Comment: I've tried this but I get the error `ReferenceError: moment is not defined`

Comment: You need to install moment with `npm i moment`

Comment: @Androz2091 You absolutely do NOT need to install a library like `moment` to do something this simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use the `.createdAt` property of User to determine their account age**

When the `guildMemberAdd` event triggers, check the joining member's `.createdAt` property. You can then use `.addRole()` to give them a role.

```js
// assuming you already have the `role` object or id
client.on("guildMemberAdd", member => {
  if (Date.now() - member.user.createdAt < 1000*60*60*24*10) {
    member.addRole(role);
  }
});
```

More detailed explanation:

- `guildMemberAdd` will fire every time someone joins a server, this will pass on the `member` object.
- We use the `user` object from that member to determine when the account was created via `.createdAt`.
- Timestamps are stored in milliseconds, so 10 days is equivalent to `1000*60*60*24*10` milliseconds.
- Compare these two timestamps, and if their account age is lower, then you give them a role.
- We're assuming you already have the `role` object. Otherwise `Guild.roles.get()` is a good way to find a role by its ID.

Comment: I take it that if you just typed  `message.channel.send(‘account was created ${Date.now() - member.user.createdAt() / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24} days ago’)`