# what is the time unit used in intervals in discord.js?

Tags: discord.js

i was working on some code, i wanted it to detect if a user is made within 2 months while doing the intervals i google how much is 2 months in milliseconds (5259600000), i got that intervals work in milli idk where i got that from, but the code doesnt really say that its 2 months, i have an alt that is 6-7 days old and still detects it as an alt, but when i increase the interval to 5259492000000 it detects accs from 2020 as an alt, so i just need help in time used in the interval, it really confused me.

hereis the code if that helps:

```
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', async member => {
    if (member.user.createdAt < 5259492000000) {
        const cachedInvites = guildInvites.get(member.guild.id);
        const newInvites = await member.guild.fetchInvites();
        guildInvites.set(member.guild.id, newInvites);
        let Muterole = member.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.id == "847963874278768650")
        member.roles.add(Muterole)
        const usedInvite = newInvites.find(inv => cachedInvites.get(inv.code).uses < inv.uses);
        const embed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setDescription(`${member.user} is an **ALT**\n created at\n${member.user.createdAt}\n Inv Code: ${usedInvite.url} \nInv Code Owner ${usedInvite.inviter.tag},||this might not be the real owner of the invite.||`) //${member.user}** is created at**\n${member.user.createdAt}\n Inv Code: ${usedInvite.url} \nInv Code Owner ${usedInvite.inviter.tag},||this might not be the real owner of the invite.||
            .setTimestamp()
        const logchannel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id === '847510771670974555');
        if (logchannel) {
            logchannel.send(embed).catch(err => console.log(err));
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Surely createdAt is a _timestamp_, not an interval - it's when, not how long ago, the account was created.

Comment: yea sorry my fault, i mean that, if the acc was created within 2 months, like if the account age is less than xxxxxxxxxxxxx milliseconds, you understand me, right? @jonrsharpe

Comment: Try looking at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58785442/discord-js-days-since-account-creation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
 if (Date.now() - member.user.createdAt < 5259600000 ) {
    // code here
  }
```

Comment: i'll luk if the code works, thanks for replying :)